# How to stop a program in Matlab without using return function?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to stop my code below from continuing on later in the program, but I cannot use a `return` statement. For example, in the `switch` statement below, if the code follows the `otherwise` section, I want the program to stop, without using a `return` or `error` function.

```
case 1
    rendevous = ('the Bridge');
case 2 
    rendevous = ('the Library');
case 3
    rendevous = ('the River Crossing');
case 4
    rendevous = ('the Airport');
case 5
    rendevous = ('the Bus Terminal');
case 6
    rendevous = ('the Hospital');
case 7
    rendevous = ('St. Petes Church');
otherwise 
    disp('Decoy Message: Invalid Rendevous Point')
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot use a return function"? As it's written your code is not a function, it is a script, so `return` wouldn't work anyway. If I understand, you could use the `otherwise` block to set `rendevous=''` for example, and then wrap any remaining code in an `if` block that won't get executed if rendevous is empty?
Also note, you don't need the parens, i.e. just do `rendevous = 'the Bridge';`
That said, this is really a basic question about generally programming, so might be worth getting some general background first.

Comment: Please give more information: why can't you use an `error` statement or a `return` statement? Is this a script or a function? Do you want MATLAB to stop execution and return to the MATLAB prompt, or do you want MATLAB to close? Note that an `error` statement in the `otherwise` case is the common and correct thing to do: the user entered an invalid data point, you need to throw an error.

Comment: @Justin the function return to stop the program from continuing any further. I do not want an error statement to come up either, just need the program to stop if the otherwise case is met. However I don't want to explicitly use that return function, rather a bunch of code or seperate functions itself to stop the program at that point.

Comment: @Justin `return` does work in scripts to exit execution.

Comment: @Laughoutloudbro121 You didn't answer Cris's question - *why* can't you use the `return` command if it does exactly what you need?

Comment: @Wolfie, its for a project I am working on for school, and one of the requrirements is that we do not use a return function.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manage/propagate for special `return` code or value (like `[]` for instance) and stop immediately I would personally use an `error` statement anyway but with special identifier and `catch` for it in main calling function to "hide" it (as it seems it is what you want to do):

```
function [] = main(id)
%[
    try
       doSomething(id);
    catch(err)
        if (strcmpi(err.identifier, 'DecoyMessage:InvalidRendevousPoint'))
             return; % Just leave the program without any error prompt (or add specific error handling code here)
        else
            rethrow(err); % Still raise other error cases
        end
    end
%]
end

function [] = doSomething(id)
%[
    ...

    switch(id)
        case 1, rendevous = ('the Bridge');
        case 2, rendevous = ('the Library');
        case 3, rendevous = ('the River Crossing');
        case 4, rendevous = ('the Airport');
        case 5, rendevous = ('the Bus Terminal');
        case 6, rendevous = ('the Hospital');
        case 7, rendevous = ('St. Petes Church');
        otherwise, error('DecoyMessage:InvalidRendevousPoint', 'Invalid rendezvous point');
    end

    ...
%]
end
```

This way, based on error identifier, people calling your function can decide how to appropriately handle it (throw or not or do special thing).

All matlab builtin errors and warning have identifiers, and it is a good thing to add identifiers to custom errors and warnings you may raise. This way people calling you code can decide for handling these errors as they wish to or temporarily (or definitely) disabling these warnings depending if they consider it is appropriate or not. See more in the following links:

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/respond-to-an-exception.html
https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html#d122e1435922

PS: Bad habit, but of course you can put everything (i.e. `main` and `doSomething`) in a single routine if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you cannot use `return`, which you *should* be using here, you could instead do this more complex logic (as first suggested [by Justin in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054198/how-to-stop-a-program-in-matlab-without-using-return-function/64071810?noredirect=1#comment113269769_64054198)). I do not recommend it, but it's a work-around for a missing `return`.

```matlab
switch n
  case 1
    rendevous = ('the Bridge');
  case 2 
    rendevous = ('the Library');
  % other cases...
  otherwise 
    % Illegal case
    rendevous = [];
end
if ~isempty(rendevous)
  % continue processing here...
end
```

In the illegal case, you set a variable to a specific 'error condition' value, then test for this condition to avoid doing any more work. You can use a separate `error_condition` variable, set to `false` before the switch, and set to `true` in the illegal case, or you can use a variable you're using anyway, like `rendevous` here, set to a sentinel value, in this case the empty array.

Comment: would you be able to provide a little more detail on what I actually need to do, like I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing and my previous coding knowledge isnt exactly helping.

Comment: I think this is precisely what I suggested in my original comment! @Laughoutloudbro121, you have a full answer here. You ask for more detail, but if you don't say what exactly you want to achieve, there is no way to give you more info. Try reading [ask]

Comment: @Justin: Indeed, it is the same thing you suggested in your comment. My apologies, I hadn’t seen that. Amended the answer to give you credit.